# What is the function of ため in the sentence

Tags: meaning, conditionals

> 「~さえ~ば(なら)」は・・・が成り立つための必要最低限の条件を示す。

I do not know why the ため is used in the middle of this sentence.
As far as I know ため is used for 2 purposes: 1-原因 2-目的

成り立つ is modifying the ため, so does it mean that 成り立つ is the 原因 or 目的？

Comment: It is certainly 目的

Comment: @JimmyYang  SO what would the translation be, is this correct:  "「~さえ~ば(なら)」 is the GOAL of consisting the minimum necessary condition?"

Comment: points to a minimum necessary condition for ..... to

Comment: @JimmyYang ok but can you tell what exactly is the 目的?成り立つ?

Comment: You've omitted the whole front of the sentence.  So what the subject of 成り立つ is or what the general 目的 is is pure guess work for us.

Comment: 「~~~さえ~ば・・・」=> ~~~ is 必要最低限の条件 and・・・is something that will be 成り立つ

Comment: @A.Ellett  I did not omit anything.  This is written character by character exactly as it is from my Japanese textbook .  It is a description describing HOW to use the 「~さえ~ば(なら)」 phrase in Japanese.

Comment: OMG.  Now I better understand.  But, definitely I think it's confusing, especially for someone learning the language.  Do they not provide examples of how to use this grammar?

Comment: But now I'm not sure how you're book expects you to parse "~" vs "・・・".  It seems something is missing (not that you omitted it, but the book did) or there's mixed notion:  one squiggles and the other dots.  Hmmm.

Comment: @A.Ellett  Yes, here are several examples they give in my textbook on how to use it:  1. 太郎は漫画さえ読んでいれば退屈しないようだ。
2. 体さえ丈夫ならどんなことにも挑戦できる。
3. 一言「こめんなさい。」と言いさえすれば、相手は許してくれるだろう。
4. 自分さえ良ければ、それでいいのですか。
5. 雨さえ降らなければ、花火ができる。
6. 人に道を聞きさえすれば、迷子にならないよ。
7. 自分さえよければ満足なのですか。
Of course I understand every single one of the examples, I just did not understand the description.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `ため` in the sentence is 目的 (the goal) of 成り立つ "establish", as in "For the purpose of establishing (...)".

## English

Indicate the minumum condition for `「～さえ～ば(なら)」は・・・` to be established.

## 日本語

「～さえ～ば(なら)」は・・・が成り立つための必要最低限の条件を示す。

Answer (score 0):

I find what your book provided  a bit confusing.  So, I looked up this grammatical structure in one of my reference books.  This is what I found:

**... さえ ... たら/ ... ば**

They define the semantics of this as:

> あるものごとが実現すればそれで十分で、ほかはちいさなことだ、必要ではない、問題ではない、という気持ちを表す。

Several examples are provided using subtle changes of the grammar:

- あなたさえそばにいてくだされば、ほかにはなにもいりません。
- 今度の試験で何がでるのかさえわかったらなあ

*Source: 日本語文型辞典*  I found this grammar dictionary very useful.  It uses very simple Japanese explanations and rather straight-forward examples.  It supplemented my other learning material very well.

I leave the translation of these example sentences for you to speculate on.

But, regarding the semantics, what was expressed was

> [This structure] expresses the feeling that if a certain occurrence should happen, that would be sufficient; anything else is a small matter, not necessary, not a problem.

---

So now let's return to your question,

> What is meant by ため in this phrase 成り立つための必要最低限の条件を示す?

ため is expressing purpose.  In other words

> ...ための必要最低限

is saying

> *the absolute minimum necessary for ...*